# What do compat mean in name service switch?

Tags: debian, nsswitch.conf

What do compat mean in name service switch? /etc/nsswitch.conf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compat is used to support the +/- features of `passwd`and `group` local files. Historically if you wanted to include information from a different source e.g. NIS, you could put an entry in your password/group file `+username` `+@netgroup` which would cause the information for `username` or `netgroup` to be read from NIS. Mostly a single `+` was put at the end of the file to indicate that the whole NIS map should be used.

With NSS this is no longer required as you can now just specify the data sources in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`   e.g.

```
passwd: files nisplus nis
```

Comment: +1, absolutely, Iain.  But it's not entirely useless these days, as in some cases I do still use the `+@netgroup` entry alongside `compat` to eg allow only database developers to have logins on a dev oracle box, without either having to duplicate their login in `/etc/passwd` (making NIS redundant) or having to allow everyone with a NIS entry to be valid on that box.  Oh, and please forgive me for putting in a (possibly missing) colon.